# Capacitor Android app does not open external browser by default

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

It's a Capacitor app based on a React project. I have the opposite question to most people, it seems -- most ask how to get an external link (a link not from their domain) to open in their app. I ask how to open it outside the app, in a standard browser. Not that I prefer users to jump between applications, but, once the app opens up an external webpage, then the user can't get back into the app, since the external webpage doesn't provide a deep link back into the app. So it seems a lesser evil to necessitate jumping between applications.

What confuses me is that, based on others asking the opposite question, opening an external url in an external browser should be the default behavior, but my Android app does the reverse. The Capacitor ios app based on the same code correctly opens any external link in Safari. But my Android app opens it right inside the app, causing me to lose the app to the redirects. I didn't explicitly add any settings to result in this behavior. What gives?

Edit:
It helps to check out more simulators. The behavior occurred on a simulator, specifically the WXGA tablet with Android version 30, but not on all simulators, even those with version 30. The WXGA tablet seemed to close the app and run the web browser, since I couldn't find the app window anymore the moment the redirect to the webpage happened. It looked as if the app was running the browser content, but I now think the app was simply closed. I'm still confused why it does that, since most other simulators and the physical phone I tested on didn't behave that way.

Comment: The default is to open in external browsers, do you have allowNavigation entry inside your capacitor config file?

Comment: I don't have that entry... It appears to be an inconsistent issue. The behavior occurred on a simulator, specifically the WXGA tablet with Android 30, but not on all simulators. The version 30 doesn't seem to be the problem since other simulators with 30 is fine. It also didn't occur on the one physical phone I tested on. I'm not sure why, but WXGA tablet seemed to close the app and run the web browser, and it looked as if the app was running the browser content, but I now think the app was simply closed.